# "in" or "into" to help this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, grammar-myths

1) For the first time, I went back to China and was allowed the opportunity to see what type of environment I could have been raised **into**.

2) For the first time, I went back to China and was allowed the opportunity to see **in** what type of environment I could have been raised.

I initially had the first example and someone told me to change it to the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: I think "in"is the better preposition. And I would not worry about the preposition-ending rule for that sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence is correct—the correct preposition to go with *raise* here is *in*, not *into*. A preposition should not be at the end of a sentence in formal written English, but in a colloquial context the preposition can be placed how you did originally.

Answer (score 2):

As Tom Au explains, "in" is the better preposition.

Your first sentence is much clearer than the second sentence.  The second sentence is very confusing, so it is worse.

It is OK to end a sentence with a preposition -- even in formal writing.

I might say:

> I went back to China for the first time.  I got a chance to see what type of environment I could have been raised in.

Comment: "OK" is informal.  "Acceptable" is acceptable in formal writing.

Answer (score 1):

One is raised "in" China.

One goes "into" China.

That's the difference.